# Remove attribute from previously selected td

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to remove css' background from previously selected TD that has a unique ID number. Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("tr").click(function() {
        var fid = document.getElementById("id").value;
        if (fid != "ID") {
            //remove background color
        }
        var id = $(this).children().first().html();
        document.getElementById("id").value = '' + id;
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#000');
    })
})
```

Comment: Need to see your HTML

Comment: http://screenshooter.net/102666042/pnamexg

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML thats gets produced (i.e. view > page source)?

Comment: http://justpaste.it/nfxk